# Wordpress posts by category - placement of function output (HTML) is incorrect in the layout

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to load posts from certain categories in WordPress. All of that works fine, but I cannot achieve the desired HTML structure. What I want is:

```
<h2>Heading<a>link</a></h2>
<div class="row">
   ...posts....
</div>
```

The problem is, that when I run the code below what I get is more like:

```
<div>..post...</div>
<div>..post...</div>
<div>..post...</div>
<h2>Heading<a>link</a></h2>
<div class="row"> <!--- empty ---> </div>
```

I run the code below to query the posts and show them on the site. Note the comment where I think the problem lies. Does echo get executed before the html tags are posted?

```
<?php
    //Gets category posts
    global $wp_query;
    $cats = get_the_category();
    $tempQuery = $wp_query;
    $currentId = $post->ID;
    // related category posts
    forEach( $cats as $c ) {
        $categoryPosts=" ";
        $newQuery = "posts_per_page=8&cat=" . $c->cat_ID;
        query_posts( $newQuery );
        $count = 0;
        while (have_posts()) {
            the_post();
            if( $count<=8 && $currentId!=$post->ID) {
                $count++;
                $categoryPosts .= get_content();
            }
        }
    ?>
    <!-- The problem probably lies somewhere in this section, but I just cannot figure out what is happening -->
        <h2>More in: <a href="<?php get_category_link($c->cat_ID); ?>"><?php echo $c->cat_name; ?></a></h2>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $categoryPosts; ?>
        </div>
        <?php   
    }
?>
```

This is how I retreive the format of each post through get_content() function

```
function get_content() { ?>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' );
        if ($thumbnail) (string)$thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];
        if (!empty($thumbnail)) { ?>
            <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php } else { ?>
            <img class="media-object" src="" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php } ?>
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?> </h4></a>
</div> <?php
}
```

I think the functions just don't execute or return in the order they are written. Or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Use  an output buffer in your function and return the output

Comment: I have managed to fix it thank you. I think the problem was, that get_content() didnt echo or return the posts, but immediately outputed the html, which resulted int $categoryPosts .= get_content(); not working the way I inteded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, use a buffer inside the function, then you don't have to worry about doing buffers anywhere else on the chance you reuse your function. When you `return` the buffer, the placement of the output/html will be inserted as you intend:

```
function get_content()
    {
        ob_start(); ?>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' );
        if ($thumbnail) (string)$thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];
        if (!empty($thumbnail)) { ?>
            <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php } else { ?>
            <img class="media-object" src="" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php } ?>
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?> </h4></a>
</div> <?php
        // Assign the data to a variable
        $data = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        // Return the contents
        return $data;
    }
```

To use you can use your `.=` or you can echo like so:

```
echo get_content();
```

Doing it this way, you can convert it to a `[shortcode]` and get the same results. Food for thought.

Comment: Oh I see what you meant now... Well this solution was better and more simple as well! thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by adjusting the loops a bit. My get_content() function doesnt actually echo or return each post structure but immediately outputs it as html, which was probably why I was getting bad structuring and $categoryPosts .= get_content(); didnt work the way I imagined it would.

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $cats = get_the_category();
    $tempQuery = $wp_query;
    $currentId = $post->ID;
    // related category posts
    forEach( $cats as $c ) {
        ob_start();
        $categoryPosts=" ";
        $newQuery = "posts_per_page=10&cat=" . $c->cat_ID;
        query_posts( $newQuery );
        $count = 0; ?>
        <h2 class="new-posts">New in <a href="<?php get_category_link($c->cat_ID);?>"><?php echo $c->cat_name;?></a></h2>
        <div class="row">
        <?php
        while (have_posts()) {
            the_post();
            if( $count<8 && $currentId!=$post->ID) {
                $count++;
                get_content();
            }
        } ?> 
        </div> <?php
        ob_end_flush();
    }
?>
```